How large can the normalizer of $\mathrm{Ad}(G)$ in $\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$ be?
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}$Let $G$ be a real Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ (say reductive/semisimple if it makes the question easier).
I am interested in results/interesting facts on the normalizer of $\Ad(G)$ in $\GL(\mathfrak{g})$, i.e. the group of all invertible linear maps $T:\mathfrak g\to \mathfrak g$ with the property that for all $g\in G$ there is a $g_T\in G$ such that $$T\Ad(g)T^{-1}=\Ad(g_T).$$
In particular, I'd like to know how large this subgroup, as well as its quotient by the centralizer, can be, where "large" can have any reasonable meaning, e.g. the dimension of the spanned subspace in $\GL(\mathfrak g)$ or a comparison with another group.
I couldn't find any results on this in the standard resources (e.g. Knapp, Warner). It's unfortunately a bad question to google. It is also possible that I am overlooking some trivial facts which imply that there is not much interesting to say about $N(\Ad(G))\subset \GL(\mathfrak g)$.
I would be particularly interested in explicit computations or characterizations for $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb R)$  and other matrix groups.

There's a related notion: the centroid of a Lie algebra, that is, the centralizer of the image of the adjoint representation in $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$.

If ${\mathfrak g}$ is a simple Lie algebra then it is an irreducible $G$-module, so the centralizer consists of the scalar multiples of the identity. Now the automorphisms of ${\rm Ad}, G$ are fairly well understood, in particular there are very few outer ones. So (for ${\mathfrak g}$ simple) it looks like the normalizer of ${\rm Ad} , G$ is just a finite group $\times$ scalars $\times$ ${\rm Ad} , G$.

@PaulLevy: When you say the automorphisms of $\mathrm{Ad}(G)$ are fairly well understood, do you have good a reference for this in mind?

I'm sure this is dealt with in the Lie groups literature (I'm not an expert) but here's an algebraic groups approach: ${\rm SL}_n({\mathbb R})$ is split over ${\mathbb R}$, so has split Borel subgroups (resp. maximal tori) and any two are conjugate. So after composing with an inner one if necessary, any automorphism preserves a split Borel $B$ and a split maximal torus $T$ contained in it, but then it stabilises the basis of simple roots corresponding to $B$. So after possibly composing with an outer involution (type $A$ root system has one such) then it stabilises all root spaces, so is...l

... just conjugation with some $t\in T$. In other words, the automorphism group of ${\rm SL}_n({\mathbb R})$ (which is the same as that of its adjoint group) is generated by inner automorphisms and the outer automorphism $g\mapsto g^{-T}$ (transpose inverse). Something very similar should hold for other types, perhaps with complications when not split real.
